# Exponential Distribution problems

Tags: probability

I have two questions dealing with the exponential probability. For the first problem, I just need to make sure what I did was correct. For the second problem, I don't want the answer but advice on what the 100pth percentile is. If possible, can someone describe it as if they were describing it to a child? Thanks!

1. (a) If i'm given a mean value of $30$. Find $\lambda$.

*Answer* - Since the mean was $30$, I set it equal to $\frac1{\lambda}$. Mean in this case would be the expected value. So then $\lambda = \frac1{30}$ or $0.0333$.

(b) What is the probability of $x = 50$.

*Answer* - I did $F(50;\frac1{30}) = 1 - e^{-1/30}(50)$ to get the value of 81.11%

(c) Suppose that a man made it through the first $30$ minutes of a lecture. What is the probability that he will finish the last $20$ minutes of the $50$ minute lecture.

*Answer* - For this problem I was finding the probability of $(30 \le x \le 50)$ which is
$F(50;\frac1{30}) - F(30;\frac1{30})$ and got an answer of $17.90$%.

1. This is the problem I'm having trouble with. If $X$ has an exponential distribution with parameter, derive a general expression for $(p)$ (the (100p)th percentile of the distribution). Using the result find an expression for the median $~$ of $X$.

*Answer* - Is the 100pth percentile would be if I set $F(x;\lambda) = 1$?

Comment: The probability that $X=50$ is $0$. You calculated $\Pr(X\le 50)$. The probability that $X=50$ is the integral from $50$ to $50$ of our density function.

Comment: The $95$-th percentile is the number $a$ such that $\Pr(X\le a)=0$ is $0.95$. The fiftieth percentile (median) is the place $m$ such that $\Pr(X\le m)=0.5$.  By the way, if on the lecture question you are (unreasonably) expected to use the exponential distribution, answer is not right. We need to use conditional probability, or, if you have done it, the memorylessness of the exponential.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Hey so would part C be correct? And similarly, why do I need to take the integral for the function lambda(e^-lambda(x))

Comment: Problem 1c) is woefully underspecified. If we make the ridiculous assumption that the time the person sits is exponentially distributed with mean $30$, then we want the **conditional probability** that $X\ge 50$ given that $X\ge 30$. It turns out that (for the exponential) the probability is $e^{-20\lambda}$, in other words the fact the person made it throgh $30$ minutes is basically irrelevant.  The previous comment already said the answer is not right.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Hey in that case it would result in a different answer. If we know the lecture time is 50 minutes and he made it through the first 30. Why would F(50;(1/30)) - F(30;(1/30)) give different results than just doing e^(1/30)(-20)>

Comment: The last number you wrote is correct. As to why your suggested number $\Pr(X\le 50)-\Pr(X\le 30)$, that gives the probability that $30\lt X\le 50$, which is not what you are asked for. And you can verify by calculation that it indeed gives a different number.